# What is the Standard Way to Make Anchor Link with Attributes: Title, rel, target?

Tags: html, hyperlink, seo, rel, microblogging

Experts

I am confused as how to add the following attribute in the anchor links.

What should be the sequence ?

**1:**

```
<a href='https://copybloggerthemes.com/' title='Blogger Templates' rel='dofollow' target='_blank'>Copy Blogger Themes</a>
```

**2:**

```
<a href='https://copybloggerthemes.com/' rel='dofollow' title='Blogger Templates' target='_blank'>Copy Blogger Themes</a>
```

**3:**

```
<a href='https://copybloggerthemes.com/' target='_blank' rel='dofollow' title='Blogger Templates'>Copy Blogger Themes</a>
```

All the above have three attributes **target**, **rel**, **title**, now I am confused which one is the perfect one.

I am confused which one attribute should be right after another ?

**Which one is SEO friendly ?**

Comment: 1. Why did you leave out the other possible variants? 2. Asking for SEO advice is off-topic here. If you are interested what HTML has to say about this, please [edit] your question and remove the SEO side question. 3. Are you aware that there is no `dofollow` link type?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your HTML question of which order the attributes should be in, it makes absolutely no difference, and all of those versions are 100% equal.

Further, as others have mentioned, there is no such thing as "rel= dofollow", and by default, all links are "follow" links. The only time you should use this attribute is when you want a link to be "no follow". Then you would have `rel="nofollow"` as an attribute.

So, your anchor tag should look something like this:

```
<a href='https://copybloggerthemes.com/' title='Blogger Templates' target='_blank'>Copy Blogger Themes</a>
```

But as I noted, the order of the attributes doesn't matter in the slightest.

As unor said, the SEO Friendliness question is off-topic here.